# uninitialized class variable @@schemes in URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am trying to migrate schemas but when I do the following logs are shown :

```
$ rails db:migrate
rails aborted!
NameError: uninitialized class variable @@schemes in URI
Did you mean?  scheme_list
D:/Projects/lms-2021/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
D:/Projects/lms-2021/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
D:/Projects/lms-2021/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
D:/Projects/lms-2021/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:9:in `require'
bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

how to fix this?

- windows 10 pro
- git bash terminal
- rails v 5.1.7
- ruby v 3.1.2

Comment: Facing this issue after upgrading ruby version from 2.7.0 to 3.1.0

Comment: I am new to rails and I am using ruby v 3.1.2 from the beginning. I cloned this code from another repository and facing this issue while setting up everything in my local system. @Anbazhagan

Comment: I resolved the issue, For me I had to upgrade this particular gem 'globalid' earlier it was 0.4.2 and upgraded to 1.0.0

Comment: I didn't have that gem previously so I had to include it. Then I bundle install and it's now working pretty fine. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73559113/uninitialized-class-variable-schemes-in-uri#comment129918304_73559113), installing or updating the gem 'globalid' worked for me.

Add `gem 'globalid', '~> 1.0'` and then run `bundle install`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could share the code of your migration that you're running and the code of URI as well. Apparently, the class variable @@schemes in URI is not initialized.

> you can initialize it using (or equals) || =

for example, if @@schemes is an  array you can do something like that:

```
@@schemes ||= []
```

Comment: I cloned this code from another repository. It's an entire application more precisely which has almost 100 migrations pending. I am trying to set everything up to make this work in my local system but facing this issue. Also, please tell me where can I find the URI code you mentioned. :) @Mohsin

Comment: @LabaniDas as the Logs showing, URI is a class that contains an unutilized class variable just search URI class in your project and initialize the value of @@schemes then again run the migrations and see if the same error still occurs